# Add internal link in multisite project

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

We have a project with 2 sites set up via Bindings in IIS.

All works well apart from when a content editor adds an internal link. Sitecore stores a value in the field such as

```
/OSS/Home/Assets/Freshwater wildlife
```

But the link doesn't resolve (404) until we remove the site name and Home to get a path

```
/Assets/Freshwater wildlife
```

I think the full path, `/OSS/Home/Assets/Freshwater wildlife`, is correct but how do we get Sitecore (6.5) to recognize this URL?

Answer (score 1):

first of all, you need to ensure your solution use correct hostnames when you rendering that links.

Please check your site configuration :

```xml
<site name="website_1" hostName="www.site1.com" language="en" cacheHtml="false" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" rootPath="/sitecore/content/site1" startItem="/home" database="web" domain="extranet" allowDebug="true" htmlCacheSize="10MB" registryCacheSize="0" viewStateCacheSize="0" xslCacheSize="5MB" filteredItemsCacheSize="2MB" enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="true" enableDebugger="true" disableClientData="false" />
<site name="website_2" hostName="www.site2.com" language="en" cacheHtml="false" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" rootPath="/sitecore/content/site2" startItem="/home" database="web" domain="extranet" allowDebug="true" htmlCacheSize="10MB" registryCacheSize="0" viewStateCacheSize="0" xslCacheSize="5MB" filteredItemsCacheSize="2MB" enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="true" enableDebugger="true" disableClientData="false" />
```

if it's something like this. 
   Also please check if `Rendering.SiteResolving` is true on web.config.

```xml
<setting name="Rendering.SiteResolving" value="true" />
```

How you render your links on code  ?

If you render with  :

```csharp
Sitecore.Links.UrlOptions defaultOptions = Sitecore.Links.UrlOptions.DefaultOptions;
string itemUrl = Sitecore.Links.LinkManager.GetItemUrl(item, defaultOptions);
```

please add:

```csharp
defaultOptions.SiteResolving = true;
```